# Error al intentar consulta en Oracle con NodeJs

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, oracle

Estoy intentando recibir una consulta `SQL` utilizando `NodeJs` pero me arroja los siguientes errores:

> (node:1876336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

> (node:1876336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting
> a promise which was not handled with .catch().

> (node:1876336) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

El código `server.js`:

```javascript
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const router = express.Router()
const oracledb = require('oracledb')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

const connAttrs = {
    user: 'bi_src',
    password: 'bi_src',
    connectString:
        '(DESCRIPTION =(LOAD_BALANCE = ON)(FAILOVER = ON)(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.112.95)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.112.95)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC))))',
}


app.get('/ejemplo', function (req, res) {

    oracledb.getConnection(connAttrs, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            // Error connecting to DB
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            res.status(500).send(
                JSON.stringify({
                    status: 500,
                    message: 'Error connecting to DB',
                    detailed_message: err.message,
                })
            )
            return
        }
        

        connection.execute(
            'SELECT G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.GSCF300',
            {},
            {
                outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT, // Return the result as Object
            },
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                    res.status(500).send(
                        JSON.stringify({
                            status: 500,
                            message:
                                'Error getting the dba_tablespaces',
                            detailed_message: err.message,
                        })
                    )
                } else {
                    res.status(202).send({
                        message: 'Resultados',
                        result })
                }
                // Release the connection
                connection.release(function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message)
                    } else {
                        res.status(202).send({
                            message: 'Petición exitosa',
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        )
    })
})

app.listen(4500, () => {
    console.log('Live at port 4500');
})
```

A veces me devuelve la consulta y otras veces me sale el error. No entiendo la razón.

Answer (score 2):

Este error suele sucedes cuando haces que la peticion retorne mas de 1 vez dentro del metodo.

> (node:1876336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Esto se puede ver en el siguiente bloque:

```
function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                res.status(500).send(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        status: 500,
                        message:
                            'Error getting the dba_tablespaces',
                        detailed_message: err.message,
                    })
                )
            } else {
                res.status(202).send({
                    message: 'Resultados',
                    result })
            }
            // Release the connection
            connection.release(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message)
                } else {
                    res.status(202).send({
                        message: 'Petición exitosa',
                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

Aquí tu usas varias veces el `res.status().send()` sin un return correspondiente. Recuerda que el `res.status().send()` se ejecuta y retorna una respuesta del servidor, pero el codigo sigue su camino.

Entonces en especifico deberias agregar los return en todas las respuestas `res.status().send()`, de esta manera se saldra del metodo cuando retorne 1 sola respuesta.

```
 return res.status(500).send(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        status: 500,
                        message:
                            'Error getting the dba_tablespaces',
                        detailed_message: err.message,
                    })
                )
```